# Displaying data from a query using a drop down list selection mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am sort of lost on the coding part of this problem. I have a MVC application, and I am trying to populate a queries **Where** clause as the selected value from my drop down list. Also, I am populating the drop down list from a query in the database. For example:

```
SELECT db.ID FROM Database db where ID = 1232
```

Instead of that, I want to do something like this...

```
SELECT db.ID FROM Database db where ID = "SelectedValue from Dropdownlist"
```

Model Class:

```
public string ID {get; set;}

public string Summary{get; set;}

public int Estimate {get; set;}

public List<Hello> getIDs()
        {
            var que = (from wre in db.Table
                       select new Hello{
                       ID = wre.ID
                       }).toList();
        }
```

Controller class:

```
public ActionResult Index(string? IDParam)
    {
        var model = test.getStuff();
        var que = (from wre in db.View
                   where wre.ID == IDParam //Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string?'

                   select new Hello
                   {
                       ID = wre.ID
                       Summary = wre.Summary,
                       Estimate = wre.Estimate
                   }).toList();

if (IDParam!= null & IDParam.HasValue)
       {
           model = model.Where(x => x.ID == IDParam); //Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string?'
       }
 return View(model);
    }
```

View Class:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ID", ViewBag.Releases as SelectList, "ID", new {@id="rel" })

<table> 
       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)</th>
       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Summary)</th>
       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estimate)</th>
</table>

<script>
 $("#rel").change(function () {
    var selectedId = this.val();
location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "SampleController", new {selectedId="_selectedId"})'.Replace("_selectedId",selectedId);
            });
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine, but now, I am lost on the coding aspect of it. I can see the alert every time I change the ID from the drop down list. However, there is no change in the data being displayed (I know I am missing a lot). If anyone can help me out here, that would be great, thank you!

Comment: You want to change the data in your view when user selects an item from the SELECT element ? You have not shared how your view looks like yet!

Comment: I have edited the code @Shyju

Comment: Are you wanting to update the `<table>` based on the selected option?

Comment: You can use ajax to get the update HTML markup for the table (your action method has to return partial view for the table). Another option is to do a form submit to your action method with the selected option value in querystring and have your action method return the view result with filtered data.

Comment: @Peter: 'string?' does not make any sense to me, string is a reference type and is nullable it-self, why would you make it nullable by suffixing '?' to it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try adding where clause in Linq

```
where wre.ID == IDParam
```

2) Change que to instance of your class and get firstOrDefault instead of List

3) Try passing instance of your class as a model in view

```
return View(test);
```

Comment: I now need to display the data based on the selected list, I have fixed that problem

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to get changed Id as below :

```
$("#rel").change(function () {
              // alert("Changed");
var selectedId =this.value;
        });
```

2- If you want to reload your page then you need to set a `parametre` to your `[HttpGet]` Method :

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? selectedId) // selectedId
        {
            var que = (from wre in db.View
                       select new Hello
                       {
                           ID = IDParam
                           Summary = wre.Summary,
                           Estimate = wre.Estimate
                       }).toList();

     ViewBag.Releases = new SelectList(test.getIDs(), "", "ID");
var model = test.getStuff();
if(selectedId!=null && selectedId.HasValue)
{
   // do some stuff with your selectedId
   // if working method is test.getStuff(), then maybe you can use like code below:
model = model.Where(x=> x.Id==selectedId);

}
     return View(model);
        }
```

and in your View:

```
  $("#rel").change(function () {
                      // alert("Changed");
        var selectedId =this.value;
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "YourController", new {selectedId="_selectedId"})'.Replace("_selectedId",selectedId);
                });
```

3- If you dont want to reload page then you need to use `Ajax`request, You must create a new method for get data by selectedId,

// Your view.

```
   $("#rel").change(function () {
                  // alert("Changed");
    var selectedId =this.value;
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "'@Url.Action("GetDataBySelectedId","YourController")'",
  data: { selectedId: selectedId }
})
  .done(function( data) {
// Delete your table, and fill table with your data with jquery. 
  });
});
```

// your Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDataBySelectedId(int? selectedId)
{
// Do some stuff for get your data.
var data = yourData.Where(x=> x.Id = selectedId.Value);
return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: thank you for a great response, however every time I do this: "(string? SelectedID) it throws me this error: Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string?'

Comment: Was not that helpful ? Sorry, I didnt understood this.

Comment: It was helpful, just giving me errors like i described in the Edits.

Comment: What is the `Rel_ID` , `RelaseId`, whats doing your  `test.getIds()` method. What is your `variables type`  You are not giving us enough information. I was just try to tell you 2 way for help you.  
If you can be obvious, I think we can fix this problem together with you.